# Apache server - how to and where

Tags: php, apache

I am learning PHP and need to download the Apache server. I have a 64 bit pc, where can i download it, also using Windows Vista and also which one is recommended.

Sorry Instructor said not to use XAMP - forgot to mention

Comment: Get [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). Also this should be on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: Apache only has 32 bits version and you can use with no problems http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache//httpd/binaries/win32/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: Which version should i download if i have a 64 bit pc?

Answer (score 0):

Two alternatives:

http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php

http://www.apachefriends.org/es/xampp.html

Many recommend xampp over wamp.

Comment: Thank you , I cant use XAMP i need Apache only

Answer (score 0):

Download [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

It is made exactly for your situation.

Includes php mysql apache and a ton of other stuff.

Comment: Hello, sorry i forgot to mention i cant use XAMP

Comment: I just want the Apache server

Comment: Then download it. It isn't hard if you follow directions. Bet youa  dollar he said don't use xampp so you can experience the pain of configuring Apache for the first time ever ;)

Comment: Which version should i download for a 64 bit pc?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going with

http://www.easyphp.org/

or

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

Comment: I cant use XAMP, i only need Apache

Comment: if u only  want apache go over here http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi

Answer (score 0):

no 64bit, only [32bit with ssl](http://apache.lehtivihrea.org//httpd/binaries/win32/httpd-2.2.19-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8r.msi).